# Prevent volume deletion on docker compose down?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

docker compose up and docker compose down work like a charm: creating everything from scratch and wiping without a trace.

That puts data in the volumes at the mercy of “fat fingers” typing down instead of stop.

Is there a setting in the docker-compose.yml to tell: don’t nuke this volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, `docker compose down` won't delete volume, but if you didn't specify the volume name, it will create a new volume as default to bind.

And every volume docker create won't delete until you type `docker volume prune`, you can check by `docker volume ls` to see if there is a lot of none-name volumes.

You can create a volume by `docker create volume example`, and define to use it in `docker-compose.yml`, then it will use same volume on next `docker compose up`.

For example what I did:

1. Create volume by `docker volume create mongodb`.
2. Edit `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
services:
    mongo:
        ...
        volumes:
            - mongodb:/data/db

volumes:
    mongodb:
        external: true
        name: mongodb
```

Docker document also said **removing the service doesn’t remove any volumes created by the service. Volume removal is a separate step**, more details see [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-service-with-volumes).

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

**Option A:**

Create the volume manually:

```
docker volume create web_data
```

And mark it as external in your docker-compose.yaml file:

```
volumes:
  web_data:
    external: true
```

**Option B:**

Mount a host directory as the volume:

```
volumes:
    - /path/to/host/directory:/path/to/container/directory
```